# File location using MATLAB GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, sensors

I am working on Motion Sensor. The sensor reads data and the MATLAB code saves it in hard disk on specific location. Now, I need to add the functionality on my MATLAB GUI which shows the location of the file that is stored on hard disk.

e.g. the file name "xyz.dat" is stored in "D:\". the MATLAB function uigetdir will not work here I think.. Is there any other matlab defined function to access it ?

Kind Regards,

Farhan

Comment: ...[`msgbox`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/msgbox.html)?

Comment: do you want to search that path in file system or you want to display in your GUI.

Comment: @ User1551892: I want to display that path to my GUI .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `uigetfile()` and `fullfile()`:

```
[filename, pathname] = uigetfile({'*.*';'*.dat'}, 'Select a dat file...');
fullPath = fullfile(pathname, filename);
```

Comment: when dealing with file names and paths you want to be os independent, therefore, simple `strcat` won't work for you while `fullfile` takes care of everything for you. Try porting such matlab code from windows to linux and you'll see how `fullfile` is your best friend...

Comment: Thankyou for help.. One more thing, which may look little stupid...

OK, the fullPath will give me the file name... Now, how should I access this through GUI ?

Comment: @Farhan You just select it through GUI, just like you open a .m file in Matlab.